# XSL fo:block long word not wrap in table cell

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop, xslt-grouping

I have tried wrap-option="wrap" and zero-width-space in fo:block but it's not working as excepted even I have used hyphenation=" true" is not working for alphanumeric words. Could you please help me to resolve this wrap issue

[Table pdf view]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hggq0.png

```
 <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="{$colspan}" number-rows-spanned="{$rowspan}" padding-before="4pt" padding-after="1pt" padding-start="4pt" padding-end="4pt">
            <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" start-indent="1pt">
                <xsl:attribute name="text-align">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@align">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@align"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="ancestor::tgroup/colspec[number($entry)]/@align">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tgroup/colspec[number($entry)]/@align"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="ancestor::tgroup/@align">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tgroup/@align"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise> left </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="ancestor::thead">
                    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
            <xsl:call-template name="indicateChangesEnd">
                <xsl:with-param name="changeType" select="../@changeType"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="changeMark" select="../@changeMark"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </fo:table-cell>
```

xsl:fo

```
<fo:table-cell padding-after="2pt" padding-before="2pt" number-rows-spanned="1" number-columns-spanned="1" border-top="1px solid black" border-bottom="1px solid black" border-left="1px solid black" border-right="1px solid black">
<fo:block wrap-option="wrap" start-indent="1pt" text-align="left">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhvvvvvvyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjgggggggggggggggggggggggg7777777777777777777777777777777777777777</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-after="2pt" padding-before="2pt" number-rows-spanned="1" number-columns-spanned="1" border-top="1px solid black" border-bottom="1px solid black" border-left="1px solid black" border-right="1px solid black">
<fo:block wrap-option="wrap" start-indent="1pt" text-align="left">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no `keep-together` on the `fo:table` or `fo:table-row`? (there is not much we can say by looking at just a partial xslt; a minimal FO example would be much better)

Comment: @lfurini Yes, There is no keep-together in fo:table and fo:table-row.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your current output?  I can't see what where you would have a problem with word-wrap unless the table is very narrow.

Comment: @TonyGraham, I have added the output can you please look into this